# Where can I find a list of UK keyboard keycodes?

Tags: keyboard, keycode

I am developing a UK keyboard. I am unable to find a list of keycodes for a UK keyboard.

I have tried changing the Regional settings in control panel to United Kingdom Extended thinking that it might change my US keyboard keycodes to a UK one, but that didn't work.

Thanks